# For which $f(x)$ does the solution exist for an arbitrary $c>0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have the problem $$y''+4y=f(x), \ y(0)=0, y(c \pi )=0$$ with $c>0$ and $f(x)$ an arbitrary smooth function.

1. For which values of the parameter $c$ has the problem always an unique solution?
2. For which $f(x)$ does the solution exist for an arbitrary $c>0$ ?

For the first part we have to check when the corresponding homogeneous problem has only the trivial solution.

The homogeneous problem is $y''+4y=0, \ y(0)=0, y(c \pi )=0$.

The general solution is $y(x)=a\cos (2x)+b\sin (2x)$.

From $y(0)=0$ we get $a=0$. So we get $y(x)=b\sin (2x)$.

From $y(c \pi )=0$ we get $b\sin (2c \pi)=0$. To get the trivial solution we have to get $b=0$ and so $\sin (2c \pi)$ must be different from $0$, so we have $$\sin (2c \pi)\neq 0 \iff 2c\pi \neq n\pi, \ n \in \mathbb{N} \ \iff c\neq \frac{n}{2}, \ n\in \mathbb{N}$$

Is that correct?

Could you give me a hint for the second part?